# Php Undefined Offset Error While Printing Table

Tags: php

I'm tried to call the variable but I get this error Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/databasetwo/untitled.php on line 113

This code print a table to Html I want to do it programmatically so the array can print the amount selected.

```
$id = "table" ;
// echo "<table id=$id><tr><th>Title</th><th>Price</th><th>Number</th></tr>";
echo "<table id=$id>";
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
        for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $amount ; $i++) {
        echo "<td>{$row[$i]}</td>";
        /*echo "<td>{$row[1]}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row[2]}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row[3]}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row[4]}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row[5]}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row[6]}</td>"; */

}

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

If I leave it $row[0], 1, 2 etc. Will Work. The error I'm getting is Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/databasetwo/untitled.php on line 113

Comment: check value of $amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting from 0, make sure for ending criteria you add `value - 1`.

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $amount - 1 ; $i++) {
```

Or remove `=` in loop like this,

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $amount ; $i++) {
```

Comment: @user3171557 Glad it helped you:)